# PHP page times out and is blank when running SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: php, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a PHP page that calls a SQL Stored Procedure.
The procedure is an insert statement that inserts 40,000 records...

```
INSERT INTO CJFDEV.JDE_CRP.CRPDTA.F3002
SELECT * FROM F3002

SELECT 'HEY HEY'
```

The PHP page never waits until it’s done…it will time out and just bring up a blank page.
The insert statement finishes, but the script never moves on to display “HEY HEY”.
If I modify it to only insert 19,000 records, it will finish and display “HEY HEY” every time.
I have increased the time out setting in the PHP.ini and for the webserver itself.
I have also increased the webserver memory setting.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where are the statement termination characters?

Comment: What happens if you `set_time_limit(0);` at the start of your script? What does the web server log have to say about it?

Comment: What about your browser's timeout? That's completely independent of anything the server does.

Comment: I added "set_time_limit(0);" and it finished in just over a minute!   Thanks DaveRandom!